# Break line inside \proc?

Tags: algorithms, small-caps

I'm using `clrscode` to typeset my algorithms. This package provides the `\proc` command in order to typeset the name of a procedure with some nice small-caps.

In a text paragraph I refer to some procedure name and unfortunately it is very long and the `\proc` command prevents it from breaking.

How can I force it to break the line or emulate the look&feel of `\proc`?

EDIT: This is an example piece of LaTeX code, where the procedure name does not break for me:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{clrscode}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Duis nec nisi mollis augue pulvinar condimentum sed quis dolor.
$\proc{Some-Very-Long-Proc-Name-That-Does-Not-Break}(E, P, Q)$.
Nam libero metus, vehicula vitae euismod a, scelerisque eget neque.
Morbi tristique tincidunt urna ut tempor.
Vestibulum sapien justo, pulvinar a porttitor eget, vestibulum a quam.
\end{document}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, `\proc` doesn't prevent line breaks. Can you give a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)?

Comment: @egreg: I've added an example that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeX breaks inline math only after relation or operation symbols. In that case the argument of `\proc` is treated as a function name and should not be split across lines, from a mathematician's point of view.

However, in tough cases where no alternative is feasible, you can say

```
\proc{long\-procedure\-name}$(E,P,Q)$
```

specifying with `\-` the preferred points where the name can be split. I'd prefer this "manual" way than relying on the automatic hyphenation.